# Amazing error "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I used `SqlCe` as my database, but when i copied all tables into `MySql` database this exception started!

My code:

```
using (MySqlConnection conSQL = new MySqlConnection(conSQLSTR))
{
    try
    {
        conSQL.Open();
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        string errMsg = e.Message;
        MessageBox.Show(errMsg, "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                         MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return false;
    }
    using (MySqlCommand comSQL = conSQL.CreateCommand())
    {
        comSQL.CommandText = "SELECT " + Column + " FROM " + TableName
                                + " WHERE " + Column + "=@param";
        comSQL.Parameters.Add("@param", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
        comSQL.Parameters["@param"].Value = Value;
        MySqlDataReader drSQL;
        bool hasRows = false;
        try
        {
            drSQL = comSQL.ExecuteReader();
            hasRows = drSQL.Read();
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            string errMsg =e.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(errMsg, "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                             MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        if (!hasRows)
            return false;
        else
        {
            return true;
        };
    }
}
```

exception :

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Line:

```
drSQL = comSQL.ExecuteReader();
```

that's interesting because this exception was not shown in message box! its like a run-time error and it seems my `TRY` was not work at all!

Comment: Errors are usually amazing..

Comment: [rubber ducks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) are even more amazing :)

Comment: Your try is not working, because you are catching `MySqlException`, not `Exception`

Comment: Well you're only catching `MySqlException`. It sounds like this isn't a MySqlException. Where did you see it? Did you get a full stack trace? Also note that you don't need the semi-colon at the end of your `else` block - and you could remove your whole `if/else` block and just use `return hasRows;`.

Comment: I think my Rubber Duck + Jon's comment make Soner's comment less amazing :)

Comment: Don't forget to dispose MySqlDataReader...

Answer (score 1):

```
using (MySqlConnection conSQL = new MySqlConnection(conSQLSTR))
```

Behind the scenes MySQL will parse your connection string into key/value pairs with a `Dictionary`. Make sure your connection string is well formed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really **amazing** mysql connector error message because it's too generic and not describing much details or clue to exact problem source.

When you see this error you should check any **strings passed** to most recent mysql executed command specially `ConnectionString`, `Database Name`, `Table Name`, `Column Names`.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth as this thread is kinda old. But today I encountered this same error. And at first it wasn't  clear what went wrong.

After upgrading our MariaDB to 10.0.24-MariaDB-7 (Ubuntu 16.04) my .Net application caused an error on opening the connection: "The given key was not present in the dictionary.".

Updating mysql.data.dll to the newest version fixed it. (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html)